# How can I segue from UICollectionView's cells embedded inside UITableViewCell (Swift)?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, segue

I have used [this tutorial](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/) to successfully embed a `UICollectionView` inside a `UITableView` I have in my ViewController.

The following will probably make more sense if you have a quick look at the linked tutorial's code (plus its a nifty thing to learn too!):

The next step for me is to perform segues from the cells of the `UICollectionView` inside the `UITableViewCell`s of the tableView, but as the collectionView outlet is established in a separate View Controller, I am not sure how to reference it in the main ViewController.

In the TableViewCell.swift there is:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
} 

extension TableViewCell {
    func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate<D: protocol<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>>(dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {
        collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
        collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
        collectionView.tag = row
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And in the ViewController.swift I need to be able to, for instance, call the **collectionView** that is in the TableViewCell in the `prepareForSegue` function that would go in the ViewController.swift file. I just need to fill the gaps with the collectionView outlet:

```
let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
        let indexPaths = self.___________.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
        let indexPath = indexPaths![0] as NSIndexPath
        let arrayObject = self.arrayObjects[indexPath.row]
        destination.object = arrayObject
```

'object' is implemented in SecondViewController like so, `var object: PFObject!`.

I now need to fill the gap, ________, in the above code with the collectionView in order to display the correct 'object' in SecondViewController (the destinationViewController)

Answer (score 5):

1. Add Push Segue from UICollectionViewCell to **YourViewController** from IB.
2. Give an identifier to your segue ("**YourSegueIdentifier**").
3. In your custom UITableViewController or UIViewController, override **prepareForSegue()** method.

This is:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourSegueIdentifier" {
        if let collectionCell: YourCollectionViewCell = sender as? YourCollectionViewCell {
            if let collectionView: UICollectionView = collectionCell.superview as? UICollectionView {
                if let destination = segue.destination as? YourViewController {
                    // Pass some data to YourViewController
                    // collectionView.tag will give your selected tableView index
                    destination.someObject = tableObjects[collectionView.tag].someObject
                    destination.productId = collectionCell.product?.id
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I had the same problem

This is what I did :

**1. set a tag for the cell in the extension in your first View Controller**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("advertisementCollectionCell",forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AdvertisementCollectionViewCell

        // set your cell information

        cell.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell
    }
```

**2. Do a segue on the storyboard from the UIcollectionViewCell to the new View Controller**

**3. In** `prepareForSegue` **of the first TableViewController :**

```
 else if segue.identifier == "identifier"
    {

        let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DestinationViewController
        if let cell = sender as? MyCollectionViewCell
        {
            let indexPath = cell.tag
        // use indexPath :D
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i just played with the code you attached. i added segue in story board manually. its easy to call .

1) just add viewcontroller to the storyboard.
2) Controll+ drag and drop segue from `collectionview` cell

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the reference to CollectionView is connected in TableViewCell.
So, you can refer it through TableViewCell and set datasource and delegate.
To add connect into your code, you have to select the CollectionView with RightButton and drag and drop into @IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
When clicks the CollectionViewCell, collectionView(collectionView:UICollectionView, didselecteditemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) function of UICollectionViewDelegate will be called by delegate.
At that time, you can segue by calling performSegue in this function.
As you write in your code, the index of tableview is set by tag, so you can get the index by tag using collectionView.tag()
The code will be as following.
var tableViewIndex = collectionView.tag()
So you can refer the correct cell using tableViewIndex and indexPath.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var tableViewIndex = collectionView.tag;        
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Hi this works great, but I really need to be able to reference the collectionView outlet itself as I need to be able to carry across data from the cell into the destination view controller. (I should have probably made that clear in the original question sorry!) Am I able to prepare this data (from an array pulled from Parse backend) inside of didSelectItemAtIndexPath ? because at the moment it keeps throwing up errors

Comment: It's possible.
Don't you implement the delegate and datasource of UICollectionView in ViewConroller?
I think you implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource in ViewController and use setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate.If so, the didselectitematindexpath will be called when you clicks the cell.
Important is you must implement UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDatasource in ViewController and set it using setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate.

Comment: Yes that part is all fine but I need to reference the outlet in prepareForSegue for the destination view controller to display the correct data. I've updated my question to explain this better. Thanks for your help so far